# Number of all possible non-redundant comparisons that can be formed in a set of 12 elements

Tags: combinatorics

We have a set of 12 elements (A, B, C, D, E....).
I would like to know the number of ways to compare them in a non-redundant way.
For example, some comparisons could be:
A vs others;
B vs others;
A and B vs others;
A , B, E vs others;
A vs B vs E vs others...
So on until all possibilities are exhausted
Logically, redundant comparisons must be removed (A vs others equals others vs A).
Is there any formula for this?

Comment: To make sure I understand: you want comparisons defined up-front, or can they be picked based on previous comparisons? I am thinking this may be equivalent to a *sorting algorithm* but only if comparisons can be tweaked. With e.g. four elements $A,B,C,D$, and "merge sort": compare $A$ with $B$ and $C$ with $D$, but then compare the "winner" of $A$ vs. $B$ with the winner of $C$ vs. $D$... Is that allowed or not?

Comment: Possibly the number of partitions of the given set into two or more non-empty subsets.

Comment: The motivation is to know the number of models to compare all possible groupings of months of the year (e.g. March vs. April vs. others, etc).
1) All elements must be in the comparison at the same time, although they can be grouped in different ways (e.g., you can compare January vs. February vs. the rest, or December vs. the rest).
2) There cannot be redundant models (e.g. March and April vs others, equivalent to others vs April and March).

Comment: I think it is related to the number of partitions..

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $2^{12} - 1$. For a given set with $n$ elements, there are $2^n$ subsets (plus the empty set).

correction: $2^{12} - 12 - 1$ since you're not comparing elements with themselves.

Comment: That is the number of subsets in a set with 12 elements. But I need the number of all possible ways in which the 12 elements of the set can be compared.

Comment: @alberto_carm Ah, I believe I have misunderstood your question. I think you're trying to find the number of ways to partition a set of 12 objects into 2 subsets. This is obtained by calculating the Stirling numbers of the second kind. In your case S{12, 2} = 2047 different combinations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: The partitions can be into more than 2 subsets, e.g., a vs c vs others, a vs bc vs d vs ef, etc

Comment: In that case you can calculate Bell's number which is just accumulating the products of Sterling's numbers. Linked in previous wiki article

Comment: Yes, seems to be correct. Is the solution 4213597 - 1?? Thanks.

Comment: That should be correct. Sorry I'm not in front of a computer to verify this, but judging by the -1 (to account for the k=1 case), I think you have a good understanding of the concept; i.e. I'm confident you got the solution. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, it has been extremely helpful.